# Noise addition with non-step change

Tags: matlab, signals, noise

My aim is to generate noisy ECG signal. I want only a shorter pieces of signal to be noisy, so I need to implement continuous change (not step change!).

I have tried the interpolations, but there is a problem of how to go from zero level of noise to certain percent of noise, then back to zero level.
The implementation will be in Matlab.

Do you have any idea of how to implement this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have ECG experience, but I can suggest a solution:

- Create a step signal.
- Smooth the step signal using convolution with gaussian.
- Build a "Noise Signal", and multiply it by the smoothed step mask.
- Sum the "Noise Signal" with the original signal.

Here is a code sample:

```
%Read sample EEG file (MATLAB built in sample).
load('ecgsig.mat');

E = ecgsig(1:end/100); %Take only 1% of data sample

T = zeros(size(E));

%Create an stripe of ones.
T(1+end*3/8:end*5/8) = 1;

%Smooth T - create smooth change by applying gaussian filter.
%T = imgaussfilt(T, 1000);
h = fspecial('gaussian', [1000, 1] ,300);
T = conv(T, h, 'same');

%Build "Noise signal" in size of E - gaussian noise with zero mean (I used image processing toolbox function).
N = imnoise(ones(size(E))*0.5, 'gaussian', 0, 0.1) - 0.5;

%Multiply "Noise signal" by the "smooth transition" mask.
N = N.*T;

%Add the masked "Noise signal" to the original signal.
J = E + N;

figure;plot(J);grid on;
```

Result:
[image]